# What format to choose in struct unpack commannd for binary data file having data : b'@T\x89\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80$\xcds?'

Tags: struct, binaryfiles, unpack

Hi I'm trying to decode some data using struct unpack, but unable choose format as data is like b'@T\x89\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80$\xcds?'. can anyone help? I tried different dtype but none of it decoded properly.

`from struct import *`

`file=open(ch8.bin,'rb')`

```
a=[]
while byte:
enter code here
byte = file.read(8)
values = unpack('f', byte)
a.append(values)
```

file.close()

Answer (score 0):

I just solve this issue as my data file having initial data as convertor which junk for me so I read this junk data and in next variable I read data which is vital for me using,
junk = np.fromfile(file, dtype = "float32", count = 1)
data =np.fromfile(file, dtype = 'float64', sep = "", offset = 0 )
Thanks.